# Issue with run jenkins in pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I use jenkins pipeline for the first time and i want to print into the console "hello world" with pipeline job.

I create my job as below with simple script to print hello world

[image: Image pipeline]

When i run my job i have like this error :

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
java.lang.AbstractMethodError:org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.validator.ModelValidatorImpl.validateElement(Lorg/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ast/ModelASTStageBase;)Z
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ast.ModelASTStageBase.validate(ModelASTStageBase.java:49)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ast.ModelASTStage.validate(ModelASTStage.java:67)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ast.ModelASTStages.validate(ModelASTStages.java:38)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ast.ModelASTStages.validate(ModelASTStages.java:32)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ast.ModelASTElement.validate(ModelASTElement.java:256)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ast.ModelASTElement.validate(ModelASTElement.java:247)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ast.ModelASTPipelineDef.validate(ModelASTPipelineDef.java:49)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ast.ModelASTMarkerInterface$validate.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.parser.ModelParser.parsePipelineStep(ModelParser.groovy:258)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.parser.ModelParser.this$2$parsePipelineStep(ModelParser.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.parser.ModelParser.parse(ModelParser.groovy:156)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2005.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.parser.ModelParser.parse(ModelParser.groovy:123)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.parser.ModelParser.parse(ModelParser.groovy)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.parser.GroovyShellDecoratorImpl$1.call(GroovyShellDecoratorImpl.java:78)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1065)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:327)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: It should work, you're using the pipeline example provided by Jenkins. Did you add any additional configuration?

Comment: I'm also facing the sample problem. Did you found any solution to this issue?

Comment: any solution now?

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by a plugin version mismatch.Pipeline-model-api and

Pipeline-model-definition plugins should be synched to solve this issue.

Get latets version of both plugins from

https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/

problem will be resolved when both plugins versions will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Probably caused by a plugin version mismatch.
You should update latest versions of Pipeline plugins to solve this issue.

See also [JENKINS-49643](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-49643)